# TableView rows With CheckBox in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, checkbox

I'm developing an application and am stuck on one thing. I've tried to resolve my problem on my own, but couldn't figure it out. If some one knows how to solve this, please help me out.

I created one UITableView with a checkbox in every row. When any checkbox is tapped I want only that checkbox selected, but currently only last check box is selected. I've provided my current code below, please let me know if you see anything that should be changed.

Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [selectPlayer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    checkboxButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 8, 25, 25)];
    checkboxButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [checkboxButton setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkboxButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxButton:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [checkboxButton addSubview:checkImage];
    cell.accessoryView = checkboxButton; 
    return cell;
}

-(void)checkboxButton:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [selectTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    [checkImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"]];
                    NSLog(@"button pressed at section %d and %d row", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    //[checkImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"]];
                    NSLog(@"button pressed at section %d and %d row", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i understand you right, you have a tableview with a button in each cell. Once you click a button of a particular cell, only this image should change.

Do you get the right section and row values in the NSLog output?

Comment: this will cause problem because , whenever cell are scrolled down scrolled up again , tableview wont create new cells every time, it will reuse the already allocated cells , so it will be problem, there fore store values for checkbox in some data structure like array or dictionary , set the values in array when check box is clicked while loading table view fetch the value from data structure

Comment: @user944351 No I am not getting right section and row it always show 0th section 0th row.thats why I am not getting

Comment: @pavan I am Not scrolling the table view and that is not my problem my problem when i tap first row checkbox or second row check box then every time only last row check box checked.

Comment: @vishiphone while checking in switch condition directly check for sender.tag instead of indexPath.Row

Comment: @Pavan Thanks for advise pavan before that only I tried this but it not except sender.tag i dont know why?

Comment: @vishiphone you need to get the button to change its image , you are setting image of of some other variable checkImage . so setImage for sender along with typecasting sender as UIButton , tell if its working

Comment: Ok pavan I will check and tell You its working or not.Thanks for reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are not using the right method, I think you need to implement the

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath{ }
```

here you have the indexPath for the selected row, and the instance of the tableView, all you need to do is instantiate the TableViewCell and check your checkmark.

Comment: Dear marcos i know this method can you please tell me for what purpose and which code I will paste in this method from my above code.

Comment: The purpose of this method is to handle when a single row is selected or tapped on. When that selection occurs there are a few different methods which are called and this is the most common one that is used to handle updates to the selected row. You should get the selected row from the indexPath provided and add your image to it at that time.

Answer (score 0):

declare the checkbox button inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`